# How to detect soft keyboard visible/invisible in Android from System Overlay View?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keyboard

I am wondering if it is possible to detect if the keyboard is visible or hidden from my view that is System Overlay View. I need to push the view on top of the keyboard when it becomes visible. And at the current moment if the view is on the bottom of the screen - it still remains there when the keyboard is visible. I think that this is not possible, but may be.....

Comment: have you tried `fitsSyetemWIndows=true` 
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Comment: @Anmol - Yes, I've tried this solution. Not working for me

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

i guess you want to hide the soft keyboard, to hide it try adding the following to the activity tag in your manifest.xml file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

or try this from your code

```
InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```